# Allowing a subset of mouse messages to pass through a control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Lets say I have two elements in XAML.  For illustrative purposes, lets say I have a listview and a grid.  Like this:

```
<ListView Name="MyList> />
<Grid Name="MyGrid" Background="#80FF0000"/>
```

I use the grid to place a big red semi-transparent overlay on top of the listview (ie. the grid is higher in the Z-order).

Now, this arrangement means the grid will block mouse messages from going to the underlying listview, which is exactly what I want... and that much works well.

But the unintended consequence is that the grid will also block mouse-wheel messages from being received by the listview, which is not what I want.

So I would like to know if it is possible to fiddle with the hit-testing of the grid to allow mouse messages to *go through* to the underlying listview but still block right/left clicks, drag drops, etc.

Alternately, is it possible to preview the mousewheel messages on the grid and 'forward' them to the underlying listview?

I am happy with any xaml or code-behind solution.  (I swear I've done this before, but for the life of me I just can't seem to figure out a simple approach).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to make some mouse events hit testable and others not - which is what you would have to do with your current arrangement.  If the `ListView` were a child of the `Grid`, however, you would be able to take advantage of routed events to achieve your desired behavior.  In this scenario you would want to change the opacity of the `ListView` rather than the `Grid`.  The end user will be none the wiser - it should still look like a semi-transparent overlay on top of the `ListView`.

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid" 
      Background="#FFFF0000">
    <ListView Name="MyList" 
              Opacity="0.5" />
</Grid>
```

Then in code behind if you let 'MyGrid' handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event, that will prevent the `MouseDown` event from bubbling up to 'MyList' but still allow the `MouseWheel` event through.

```
this.MyGrid.PreviewMouseDown += (o, e) =>
{
    e.Handled = true;
};
```